# Expand nav on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

The problem I encounter is that I want the nav to expand when I click on a button, but what it now does is that it looks like it kinda float above the rest. Or that it is another div that is created underneath it.

For a clearer understanding of what is happening I would recommend that you run the snippet, because it is hard for me to explain what really happens.

This problem is only relative for the mobile menu.

I also use the bootstrap css, but that onlt effects `<div class="container">`.

The things I already tried to fix the problem are:

- Removed the bootstrap css
- Changed the `<nav>` to a div element
- Changed all the positions to relative
- Changed somethings about the float

So this are the most important parts of the code I use.

```js
/*JS for the hide/show of the menu*/
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".menu-trigger").click(function() {
  $(".menu").slideToggle(400, function() {
   $(this).toggleClass("nav-expanded").css('display', '');
  });
 });
});
/*JS for the dropdown in the menu*/
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").click(function () {
        $('li > ul').not($(this).children("ul").slideToggle()).hide();        
    });
});
```

```css
body{
    background-color: white;
}
.container{
    background-color: #919191;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px black;
}
nav {
    background: #7D7D7D;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #303030;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 2px 10px;
}
nav ul, li, a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
nav a, a:link, a:visited, a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: block;
}
ul > li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}
ul > li a {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 40px;
    height:40px;
    display:block;
    padding:0px 10px;
}
nav ul li a:hover{
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #666666;    
    display: block;
}
nav ul li ul {    
    background: #333333;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #303030;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:100;
}
nav ul li ul li {
    float: none;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 150px;
}
.menu-trigger{
    display: none;
}
.burger{
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
    width: 22px;
    height: 2px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    margin: 5px auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 760px){
    .menu-trigger{
        display: block;
        background-color: #BFBFBF;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #303030;
        height: 35px;
        padding: 5px 5px;
        margin: 3px 10px;
        width: 40px;
    }
    .nav-expanded{
        display: block;
    }
    nav ul{
        display: none;
        background: #7D7D7D;
        border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px; 
    }
    nav ul li{
        float: none;
        padding: 0;
    }
    nav ul li:first-child{
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
    nav ul li ul {    
    background: #7D7D7D;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index:0;
    }
    nav ul li ul li {
    line-height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
    }
}
.active{
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #404040;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">  

    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <header>
        <nav>
          <button class="menu-trigger">
            <span class="burger"></span>
            <span class="burger"></span>
            <span class="burger"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="menu">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-trigger"><a href="#">Dropdown<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a> 
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>   
    </div>  
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

And if there are somethings unclear please ask and maybe I can make a clearer. Also if there is something wrong with the post I would like to hear it.

Comment: I dont really get the question . do you want this menu button to expand and then show the menu vor wat ?

Comment: What I wanted was to let the darker grey are to expand when you click on the button and then let you show the menu. Thanks for the comment, but the problem is already solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the DEMO [here](http://jsbin.com/bucolacovu/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

You had a fixed height for "nav" that was 40px with border radius 4px, which was making it not to expand and look like a separate element in itself even though the expanded list was inside it. 
What you need to do is to give it an auto height, so that it has the height equal to the height of all the child elements together.

Check the demo, let me know if you wanted this only.